# Is there any way to pass object properties dynamically as individual parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like below

```
const myObject = {
  param1: 'val-1',
  param2: myFunction,
  param3: {test: 'test'},
};
```

Now is there any dynamic way so I can pass this object properties as individual parameters like below?

```
callBack('val-1', myFunction, {test: 'test'});
```

**Note:** Number of Object properties are dynamic.

Comment: This would not be dynamic `callback(myObject.param1, myObject.param2, myObject.param3)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as it is in the question, the object's properties happen to be in the order you want to pass into the callback, you can use `Object.values` and spread them:

```
callBack(...Object.values(myObject));
```

Comment: Is `Object.values()` guaranteed to return the properties in the order that they're in the literal?

Comment: Yes, except for array indicies

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013/1491895) says the requirement was added in ES2020, and all implementations already did it.

Comment: It was only *officially* added very recently, but implementations have supported it for ages